# Android Soundboard

Tags: android

***EDIT***

Ok just found out if i play any of the sounds before i try to save them it will work fine when you try to save them?????

***EDIT***

I have a soundboard that i have made which is having a small problem i am saving the sounds to the SDCARD of the phone which works fine on a android tablet with android 2.2.

But when i run on a phone using android 2.3 and try to save the sounds i get a force close error?

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.PlaySound1, R.id.PlaySound2, R.id.PlaySound3, R.id.PlaySound4, R.id.PlaySound5,};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.bentonirate, R.raw.bentonlong, R.raw.bentonshort, R.raw.ohjesuschrist, R.raw.ohjesuschristbenton, };

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };



    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }



}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}
@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }



//Save into Ring tone Folder

public boolean savering(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=50; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/ringtone/";


 String filename="Benton"+".ogg";


 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
 getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
 Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);




 return true; 
}

//Save in Notification Folder

public boolean savenot(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/notification/";


 String filename="Benton"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
 getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
 Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);


 return true; 



}
}
```

Not sure if it is to do with where i am saving the sounds if this is meant to be different for different versions? maybe this line?

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/ringtone/";
```

LogCat:

```
    12-02 16:03:28.521: D/dalvikvm(7148): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 42K, 50% free 2714K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 34ms
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_native_setup
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): SoundPool constructor: maxChannels=4, streamType=3, srcQuality=0
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_load_FD
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): load: fd=42, offset=865776, length=39946, priority=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): create sampleID=1, fd=43, offset=39946, length=865776
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): doLoad: loading sample sampleID=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_load_FD
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): load: fd=42, offset=905774, length=98155, priority=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): create sampleID=2, fd=44, offset=98155, length=905774
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): doLoad: loading sample sampleID=2
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_load_FD
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): load: fd=42, offset=1003982, length=28948, priority=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): create sampleID=3, fd=45, offset=28948, length=1003982
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): doLoad: loading sample sampleID=3
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_load_FD
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): load: fd=42, offset=1032985, length=23394, priority=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): create sampleID=4, fd=46, offset=23394, length=1032985
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): doLoad: loading sample sampleID=4
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): android_media_SoundPool_load_FD
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): load: fd=42, offset=1056440, length=73700, priority=1
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): create sampleID=5, fd=47, offset=73700, length=1056440
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPool(7148): doLoad: loading sample sampleID=5
    12-02 16:03:28.571: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): beginThread
    12-02 16:03:28.581: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): run
    12-02 16:03:28.581: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): Got message m=2, mData=1
    12-02 16:03:28.581: V/SoundPool(7148): Start decode
    12-02 16:03:29.031: V/SoundPool(7148): close(43)
    12-02 16:03:29.031: V/SoundPool(7148): pointer = 0x45c82000, size = 552960, sampleRate = 48000, numChannels = 2
    12-02 16:03:29.041: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): callback: (1, 1, 0, 0x32fab0, 0x4051f8f0)
    12-02 16:03:29.041: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): Got message m=2, mData=2
    12-02 16:03:29.041: V/SoundPool(7148): Start decode
    12-02 16:03:29.482: V/SoundPool(7148): close(44)
    12-02 16:03:29.482: V/SoundPool(7148): pointer = 0x45d82000, size = 1048576, sampleRate = 48000, numChannels = 2
    12-02 16:03:29.482: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): callback: (1, 2, 0, 0x32fab0, 0x4051f8f0)
    12-02 16:03:29.482: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): Got message m=2, mData=3
    12-02 16:03:29.482: V/SoundPool(7148): Start decode
    12-02 16:03:29.702: V/SoundPool(7148): close(45)
    12-02 16:03:29.702: V/SoundPool(7148): pointer = 0x45e82000, size = 372736, sampleRate = 48000, numChannels = 2
    12-02 16:03:29.702: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): callback: (1, 3, 0, 0x32fab0, 0x4051f8f0)
    12-02 16:03:29.702: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): Got message m=2, mData=4
    12-02 16:03:29.702: V/SoundPool(7148): Start decode
    12-02 16:03:29.822: V/SoundPool(7148): close(46)
    12-02 16:03:29.822: V/SoundPool(7148): pointer = 0x45f82000, size = 286720, sampleRate = 48000, numChannels = 2
    12-02 16:03:29.822: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): callback: (1, 4, 0, 0x32fab0, 0x4051f8f0)
    12-02 16:03:29.822: V/SoundPoolThread(7148): Got message m=2, mData=5
    12-02 16:03:29.822: V/SoundPool(7148): Start decode
    12-02 16:03:30.213: V/SoundPool(7148): close(47)
    12-02 16:03:30.213: V/SoundPool(7148): pointer = 0x46082000, size = 1048576, sampleRate = 48000, numChannels = 2
    12-02 16:03:30.213: V/SoundPool-JNI(7148): callback: (1, 5, 0, 0x32fab0, 0x4051f8f0)
    12-02 16:03:31.914: D/dalvikvm(7148): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 12K, 50% free 2740K/5379K, external 1949K/2199K, paused 23ms
    12-02 16:03:32.004: D/dalvikvm(7148): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 49% free 2747K/5379K, external 4409K/4541K, paused 29ms
    12-02 16:03:35.217: W/ResourceType(7148): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    12-02 16:03:35.217: D/AndroidRuntime(7148): Shutting down VM
    12-02 16:03:35.217: W/dalvikvm(7148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:901)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:826)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:808)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.savering(Activity2.java:148)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.function1(Activity2.java:118)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.onContextItemSelected(Activity2.java:109)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2254)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2903)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:160)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:885)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:880)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3604)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-02 16:03:35.247: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: tl;dr. could you try to limit this to the actually relevant part?

Comment: @willtate i have added the logcat for you

Comment: @njzk2 the whole code may need to be posted incase it is to do with the sound intergers at the top... if you can see how i can strip it down i will glady do that :)

Comment: Its occuring at the line `InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);` in your `savering()` method.  The `int ressound` is coming in as `0` and that is obviously an invalid Resource ID.  This should be enough info to get you started debugging as to why that's occurring.

Comment: @willtate i appriciate your answer but i am kind of a noob to android is it possible for us to join a chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
savering(selectedSoundId)
```

It seems "selectedSoundId" may not be initialized

### EDIT

In order for your selectedSoundId to be a valid value, you need to click on the sound and have it played. Does that part happen?

Else, you have to use the same code in the function1 (and 2) methods as in the clickListener in order to find the proper soundId for the menuId.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but dont thisnk that is the issue i am still getting a force close

Comment: according to the logcat, you are trying to open raw resource 0. which does not exist. which is not what you want. There is a point in your code where you don't initialize the variable you are passing to the savering method.

Comment: Could you possiblbly point me in the right direction as to how to initialize the variable? Also this puzzles me as to how it would work on the 2.2 tablet if it wasent passing the variable in the first place?

Comment: Ok just found out if i play any of the sounds before i try to save them it will work fine when you try to save them?